# One Google Docs workbook as a database for another using a script?

Tags: database, excel, google-apps-script, google-docs

Disclaimer: I started working with spreadsheets in depth this week, prior to that it was basic usage.  I've read the rules and this does relate to programming, it's just my ignorance of programming keeps me from asking a specific question.  I'm new to this, I want to learn, I have to start somewhere.

I want to create two separate spreadsheet documents, one as a database for another.  I want one to be able to query the other in a way similar to the VLOOKUP() function or something along those lines.

These are very large files hence the need for separate documents.

I am learning about scripting and think there might be a way there.  If that's the case please appreciate that I literally started reading about scripts this morning and know nothing (yet) about them.

All I need to know is, if it's possible and what functions to use, I'll figure out how to use them. I just don't have a working knowledge of all the script functions, and a limited knowledge of spreadsheet functions.

The IMPORTRANGE() function is limited to 50 per spreadsheet, given how I want to use it, that is not enough.  Unless you know a work around.  That and I only want one cell of information at a time and it doesn't need to be displayed, just usable.

Also, efficiency is king since I'm working with such large amounts of data.  I used to have almost 1500 VLOOKUP functions as I was building what I already have and that sucker was starting to bog down.  Then I realized I didn't need a dynamic database for that aspect of the sheet.  I killed about two thirds of them and it runs much better.  I'd like to keep it that way, or at least try.

Finally I may have bitten off more than I can chew, but this has been a fun challenge for me, and I've met with success so far.  Please don't dismiss me out of hand because I don't know the right questions to ask, or I'm trying to fit a square peg in a round hole, everyone has to start somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally possible, though you will quickly find that spreadsheet functions are too cumbersome for this sort of operation. 
With Google Apps Scripts you can query and write to and from multiple workbooks with ease. You would be working in Javascript, using javascript objects and arrays.

Start by reading the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) and checking out their examples.

Comment: I am asked by the website rules not to tell you "thanks", so I won't, even though I do feel grateful for your time and willingness to help.  I will also shroud my gratitude with a question seeking clarity as directed, the "Google documentation" is a link right?  :)  Cheers!  ::looks for a "Cleric" over left shoulder::

Comment: It's a link. Specifically check out these tutorials: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles. Spreadsheet data to/from javascript objects specifically is what you're after.